# Can I use an IV curve alone to differentiate between metallic, semiconducting and insulating materials?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, insulators

Assuming the size of the bandgap is expressed as resistance in the IV curve, could I tell between metals, semiconductors an insulators by only doing an IV sweep? For example very high slopes (large $\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}V}$) would indicate metals and very low slopes would indicate insulators?

Comment: This would allow you to measure the resistance, that's about it.

Comment: Hmm well the slope of the I-V and the bandgap are only distantly related to one another.  Insulators will allow no current so that's easy to see on an I-V.  If you knew the dimensions of the sample then the resistance (slope) could be related to the resistivity and that would tell you if the material was a metal or semi.

Comment: But then semimetals through a bit of a monkey wrench in to it. Ultimately, you need to know what the band structure actually looks like.